# I posted some question in stackoverflow, I got some badges and reputation; I clean my cookies recovery

Tags: support, user-accounts

I posted some question in stackoverflow, I got some badges and reputation; I cleaned cookies from browser and now I am not able to continue using the same user I was. How can I recover, register and recover, this user?

Comment: Can you define "not able to"?

Comment: define "not able to": when I came back to post a question into stackoverflow the user name I had used, along with the reputation and badges was gone. I had a link to a question I had posted, and so a followed the link, and found a link to the user I had been user. However, I cannot take control of that user

Answer (score 2):

Login again with the same credentials you used initially..

Comment: I did not use any credentials when I started to post questions

Comment: Sounds like Veronica was using an anonymous account. Post a link to that old question

Answer (score 1):

If you provided an email address to us, use the account recovery link on the login page and enter that email address.

If you did not provide an email address to us, you'll have to register a new account and then email the URLs of both OLD and NEW accounts to us ... at the email address provided at the bottom of every page we serve.